# Cambiar formato fecha en Batch

Tags: batch, amazon-s3

Estoy creando un script en Batch que me autodescargue el backup de un S3 cada dia. Ya tengo todo lo que tiene que ver con el S3Browser pero tengo un pequeño problema al descargar el último backup (el mas reciente). A los backups se les asigna el nombre en este formato de fecha YYYY-MM-DD (ej: 2018-04-26). Como podria hacer para que el batch me cogiera la %date% de el PC y me la convirtiese al formato correcto? Aqui os dejo el script hasta el momento:

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\S3 Browser
s3browser-con
s3browser-con.exe download Server:[password] bucket/2018-04-24/ C:\Backups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final encontré otra forma de resolver el problema: creando 3 variables para los años, meses y días.

```
set ano=%date:~6,4%
set mes=%date:~3,2%
set dia=%date:~0,2%
```

Y luego substituyendo las variables en el nombre del archivo con el orden que queramos.

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\S3 Browser
s3browser-con
s3browser-con.exe download Server:[password] bucket/%ano%-%mes%-%dia%/ C:\Backups
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
set DateTimeNow=
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ "  %%a in ("%date%") do (set MM=%%a& set DD=%%b& set YYYY=%%c)
```

Es importante para este caso en `delims=/ "` dejar el espacio despues del `/`
con esto estamos estableciendo que carateres vamos a usar para hacer partir por partes la salida en mí caso al ejecutar date sale `vie. 27/04/2018` en tu caso esto puede variar, dependiendo la configuración regional. 
En mi caso windows 10 esta linea al correrla dentro de un bat sale asi `for /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %a in ("vie. 27/04/2018") do (set MM=%a  & set DD=%b  & set YYYY=%c )`

Luego por consola aparece `(set MM=27  & set DD=04  & set YYYY=2018 )`

```
set DateTimeNow=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%
```

Luego está aparece asi `set DateTimeNow=2018-27-04`

Y pues esto era lo que usted ya tenía.

```
cd %ProgramFiles%\S3 Browser
s3browser-con
s3browser-con.exe download Server:[password] bucket/%DateTimeNow%/ C:\Backups
```

[Página con ejemplo](http://graciasinternet.blogspot.com.co/2012/06/obtener-fecha-y-hora-con-cmd-de-windows.html)

[sobre tokens](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php)

Comment: Me fallan los dias: Si copio el código en un bat y hago y echo me sale este output ( -04-2018)

Comment: Ok, por favor explicate mejor.

Comment: No se por que, pero el script no me coje los dias. Tengo el idioma en Español y la fecha y hora en automático. Te ajunto una captura para que veas lo que me sale cuando ejecuto el script. https://imgur.com/a/nL5vF22

Comment: Facilitame una de toda la ejecucución del script. ocultado la data sensible me interesa la salida de la parte del for.

Comment: Al final encontré otra forma de definir la variable y el script ya me funciona correctamente. Igualmente gracias por tu ayuda. :D